# Can't Accept Answers or enter review queue

Tags: bug, status-completed

Whenever I try to enter the review queue or accept an answer, I get an error message. I also now cannot post comments.

Also, while writing this post, both "Title is Missing" and "Body is missing" is showing up, even though there is text in the fields. The same thing happens with the "Tags" field.

Comment: I just tried to provide an answer to [a question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/516899/how-do-i-stream-computer-audio-only-with-ffmpeg), but received "An error occurred submitting the answer", and also saw "body is missing" while writing answer.

Comment: Yep, me too, posted on MSE http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238734/lots-of-stuff-broken-on-ask-ubuntu

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whoops, sorry about that. We did a CloudFlare test earlier that didn't go so well, so we turned off CF, but it got accidentally turned back on later.

Should be all good now.

Comment: Thanks for the followup explanation.